# How do I import a .pfx certificate into my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I have iphone 13, but downloading the single `.pfx` certificate didn't show any option to install it, the guides on the internet suggest mailing it, so I've tried sending it to my gmail but that also doesn't show any option, how do I do it?

Comment: Try renaming it to `.p12` - both suffixes are for PKCS#12 type files, but pfx is a Windows specific suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and open it in Safari not Chrome, Edge, Firefox or Opera... then you are presented with the option to install it.